# JavaScript Regex Only returns one match

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't see where I went wrong here:

```
var TestString = '+test +"testing multi" -not -"and not this" "w00t" hehe nice +\'test this\' -\'and this as well\'';
var regex = new RegExp('([\\+\\-]{0,1}([\\\'"]).*?\\1|[^\\s]+)', 'g');
var match = regex.exec(TestString);
if (match != null) {
    for (var i = 1; i < match.length; i++) {
        alert('Match ' + i + ': "' + match[i] + '"');
    }
}
```

For some reason, only +test is matched, followed by an empty match, and that's it.

Comment: what do you expect to be matched?

Comment: +test, +"testing multi", -not, -"and not this", "w00t", hehe, nice, +'test this', -'any this as well' (comma separated list of expected matches) Regex explained: Any string enclosed within Single or Double quotes, prefixed by a '+' or '-' (or without prefix), and if that doesn't match, match any 'word' (sequence of characters that are not a space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this seems to work ok

```
var TestString = '+test +"testing multi" -not -"and not this" "w00t" hehe nice +\'test this\' -\'and this as well\'';
var match = TestString.match(/([+-]?([\\'"]).*?\2|[^\s]+)/gi)
if (match != null) {
    for (var i = 1; i < match.length; i++) {
         alert('Match ' + i + ': "' + match[i] + '"');
    }
}
```

It wasn't really on purpose... I just rewrote the RegExp to a literal, because I find that easier to read :)

Output

```
Match 1: "+"testing multi""
Match 2: "-not"
Match 3: "-"and not this""
Match 4: ""w00t""
Match 5: "hehe"
Match 6: "nice"
Match 7: "+'test this'"
Match 8: "-'and this as well'"
```

Comment: how about simply /[^\s]/gi ? Ingore, I see what you mean now

Comment: Thanks, still not 100% sure why yours works and mine doesn't :) Btw, why do you use \2? I thought the quote group would get \1 since it's completed before the main capture?

Comment: this doesn't get the first +test. is that a problem?

Comment: I only see style differences (I always try to escape + and - if I use it as a literal, and using {0,1} in stead of ?), but those don't make the difference here. It's also not the case insensitive, which isn't required. About the first result: the loop should start at 0, not 1. I did that because mine started with a double result, figured 0 would be the entire matched string (you can tell I normally do regexes in .NET :))

Comment: @NKCSS Actually \1 would be the outer, branching capture and identical to \0, so that wouldn't work right. \2 is the sub-capture in the first branch, ie. the one you want. As for the style differences, I rewrote your regexp as I would write it, just to be sure I understood it, and it happened to work. But your preferred style works fine too. The pointless case-insensitive flag I just put in out of habit, but yes, it's absolutely pointless :)